# (Java) inputmismatchexception when scanning a file

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I get java.util.inputmismatchexception when using nextDouble() on a file containing only doubles.  Here is the relevant section of code:

```
public static double[] getGravity() throws IOException
{
    Scanner file = new Scanner("SurfaceGravity.txt");
    double[] gravity = new double[8];
    for(int index = 0; index < gravity.length; index++)
        gravity[index] = file.nextDouble();  //Here is where I get the error
    file.close();
    return gravity;
}
```

And here is the contents of SurfaceGravity.txt

```
3.700465457603474
8.8661999605471
9.8
3.697967684866716
24.776754466506414
10.43814587026926
8.861473215210253
11.131680688084042
0.6128071987535232
```

I was under the impression that inputmismatchexception occurs when the token is the wrong type but as far as I can tell all of the tokens in the file are doubles so I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

There is no double value in String `SurfaceGravity.txt`. You probably want `new Scanner(new File("SurfaceGravity.txt"))`

See javadoc for [Scanner(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)):

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.

And [Scanner(File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File))

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave you haven't initialised the File you want to read from.

There are also a couple of issues with the implementation: Say for instance that the number of items within the file were to change then you'd have to change your implementation, as at the moment you are limited to 8 values.

```
public static List<Double> getGravity() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("SurfaceGravity.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(input.hasNextDouble()){
        list.add(input.nextDouble());
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Note:** It is possible to use a `double[]` if absolutely necessary, but for that you'd need to find out the number of lines in the file.